# Angular-ui-Bootstrap carousel not running infinitely

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap carousel with angular and for some reason the slides are not running infinitely, which I believe should be the way it is programmed to work from the reading of other SO answers I have carried out and also from the bootstrap documentation. I have 3 images set as slides but it only changes once and then stops(i.e. changes from image1 to image2).

My angular js looks like this:

```
this.Interval = 300;
this.slides = [
 {
  image: '/image1.jpg'
 }, 
 {
  image: '/image2.jpg'
 }, 
 {
  image: '/image3.jpg'
 }
 ];
```

My html looks like this:

```
 <section id="test">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <carousel interval="Hello.Interval">
                            <slide ng-repeat="slide in Hello.slides" active="slide.active">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-3">
                                <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <p class="quote">
                                    <span translate="{{ 'quote[' + ($index + 1) + ']'}}"></span><br>
                                    <span class="quote-author" translate="{{ 'name[' + ($index + 1) + ']'}}"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            </slide>
                        </carousel>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I have added all the html including divs that I feel are irrelevant, but perhaps these divs also have an effect. Although I did try and remove it to the bare bones but it still did not work. If the css is required please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. It was due to a bug that prevents ng-animate from working with ui.bootstrap.

The following directive solves the issue:

JS

```
app.directive('disableNgAnimate', ['$animate', function($animate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $animate.enabled(false, element);
    }
  };
}]);
```

HTML

```
<carousel disable-ng-animate>
  ...
</carousel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Paul works but destroys the animation given by ngAnimate. Actually i have problems to build a good carousel with ui-bootstrap and ngAnimate. So sad...

-- Possible Solution --

I read in angular github issues that that's a problem with actual versions, so you have to use the ngAnimate and angular 1.3.13 meanwhile the don't solve this problem. That solved my problem.

Comment: it is very annoying, but it only disables ng-animate in the carousel html element